# How to create conditional attribute in nested factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a few factories but I need to pass down an argument or trait but I'm not sure how. I need to create an extra field in my hash only if a condition_is_met.

```
  sequence :assets do |n|
    assets = []
    count = (n % 3) + 1
    while count > 0
      count -= 1
      i = (n + count) % asset_compound_ids.length
      compound_id = asset_compound_ids[i]
      asset_id, blob_name = compound_id.split(/,/)
      assets << {id: asset_id.to_i, blob: {name: blob_name, url: ASSET_ID_2_URL[compound_id]}}

      if condition_is_met
        assets[index][:blob][:asset_duration_ms] = 34564224
      end
    end   

    assets
  end

factory :layout do
    assets
end

factory :event do
    layout
end
```

Can we pass the condition down to the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a callback to the factory like this?

```
factory :layout do
  assets
  after(:build, :stub) do
    next unless condition_is_met
    assets[index][:blob][:asset_duration_ms] = 34564224
  end
```

end